# Why In latex the written part inside a column goes outside the margin?

Tags: latex, overleaf

Why the written part of my column is outside margin? How can I Fix it?

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
    \geometry{paperwidth=1080px,paperheight=1980px}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usetheme{Board}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
    
    \maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
    \colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
    \block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}
    
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.55} \block{\hspace{10cm}
    \large Scientific Relevance}{
    \textcolor{white}{\hspace{10cm}\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}}
    
\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{}
\end{columns}
    
\end{document}
```

How can I Make the written part in my column enter in my Poster instead being outside?

Comment: Surprise! You code does not compile! Do you test them before posting your questions?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have changes it, to me is compiling, sorry, and thank you

Comment: No it is not compiling, see the red marker at the top right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQEXP.png

Comment: I edited it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the tikzposter class does not care about your changed paper size. If you use one of the 3 papersizes `tikzposter` supports, so can see the whole text:

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
%\geometry{paperwidth=1080px,paperheight=1980px}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme{Board}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\node[above right,opacity=1.2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (bottomleft) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};

\maketitle[titletotopverticalspace=-8cm] % See Section 4.1
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{black}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{blocktitlefgcolor}{red}
\block{\textbf{Ultrastructural anylisis}}{}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.55} 
\block{\large Scientific Relevance}{
\small The overall \textcolor{red}{why is this outside?mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}}

\column{0.45} \block{Ciao}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are a damn Genius. Thanks a lot you saving me literally. I have the deadline 24.